# Trying to align text under an image using flexbox without flex-direction column

Tags: html, css

So I want to place my text under the image **without** changing the flex-direction from *row* to *column*.

Here is my code

```css
.img-totm {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-totm img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 20px 10px 0px;
}

.img-totm h2 {}
```

```html
<div class="img-totm">
  <img src="images/img-berryblitz.jpg" alt="">
  <h2>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h2>
  <img src="images/img-spiced-rum.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/img-donut.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/img-myrtle-ave.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/img-bedford-bizarre.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Comments aren't answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- wrap your images in div that is displayed as flex column and aligned center. Then you would have your answer, but you should be aware that your image size is a bit big, so if the viewport is small, they might overflow to next row appearing as flex-column.
- Also, use gap instead of padding to put spaces between images.

```css
.img-totm {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-totm img {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.img-totm h2 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-totm">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200/bee" alt="">
    <h2>Fall Berry Blitz Tea</h2>
  </div>

  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200/dog" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200/frog" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200/street" alt="">
  <img src="https://loremflickr.com/200/200/cat" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: The original code used CSS classes for styling, which is good practice. You've introduced inline styles here, which isn't. I suggest a move to a new custom class.